# How can I get the correct mapping for my bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 5.1, and a [Buffalo BSKBB22](https://translate.google.com/translate?depth=1&hl=en&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhermitage%2Bakihabara%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DjWO%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26channel%3Dnp&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ja&u=http://buffalo.jp/product/news/2013/09/26_02/) bluetooth keyboard.

It connects fine, and I can type with it, but the keyboard mapping is off. The keyboard itself has a Japanese key mapping, but it seems I can only select from various western and European key mappings in the settings on my tablet device.

Is there a way I can get the correct key mapping for my bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: You can try this paid app from play store [External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) or [Tincore keymapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tincore.and.keymapper)

Comment: @Lucky, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, External Keyboard Helper Pro does not include a Japanese keymapping. As for Tincore... I can barely understand it. It's not very clear on what exactly it does or how.